# android facebook authorization: onActivityResult not called

Tags: android, facebook, authorize

I build an android app connect with facebook, which has a button. When I click the button, the app will call facebook.authorize to ask permission. After return from the ask permission screen, it should call onActivityResult method. But in my case, it never call this method. I found some similar question but all the solutions don't solve my case. Here's my code when user click the button:

```
facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "read_friendlists" }, 
                new DialogListener() {
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        Log.v("complete", "complete");
                        hideNeedLoginView();
                    }

                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.v("cancel", "cancel");
                        hideNeedLoginView();
                    }

                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.v("error", "error");
                    }

                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.v("error", "error");
                    }
                });
```

And onActivityResult method:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Since the onActivityResult not called, all the onComplete or onCancel method don't called either. The Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY is not defined so that's not the problem(this is mention on facebook page). If I set the activityCode to Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH then when I clicked the button, the app not responding. And I have facebook app installed on the device. What should I do to call the onActivityResult method after authorize? Please someone help me with this since I can't find any solution anywhere.

Comment: there is a variable at top of the util.java in the Facebook SDK called something like show_debug or something like that. set this value to true and check for tag::facebook in the LOGCAT. It usually gives a good hint as what the problem may be.

Comment: @Alborz: I did what you said, unfortunately nothing show in the Logcat (tag facebook).

Comment: @ania: No, I'm quite new to all of this so I don't know what Fragment is.

Comment: @user1417127 did you really rerun the same procedure? It must should if authentication is successful or not. Remember that you need to type something in the LOGCAT in order for it to update otherwise it will not show anything.

Comment: Do you put @Override to your onActivityResult method?

Comment: @Alborz: Yes I did. In the Util.java, I set ENABLE_LOG = true; Then before call facebook.authorize, I try write something to logcat Log.v("btfb", "btfb");. When I rerun the application, logcat does show my log, but nothing from facebook after authorize

Comment: @ania: Yes but nothing difference. It still don't change anything.

Comment: @user1417127 just type tag:face in LOGCAT

Comment: @Alborz: I got it. It show this line when I click allow or cancel in the ask permission screen:  06-04 08:45:40.070: E/Facebook-ProxyAuth(7557): Failed to read calling package's signature.

Comment: @user1417127 finally, now you can check other questions, such as this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211950/facebook-sso-example-not-working-an-error-ocurred-please-try-again-later the second answer looks promising!

Comment: @Alborz: Thanks for your help but I don't think my problem is same like that one. My ask permission screen didn't show error. I can choose allow or cancel authorize. And if I allow, the app permission appear in my facebook setting page. So I think I set up the key hash right. The problem is it just not call onActivityResult when return from facebook.

Comment: Thank you so much! The `android:noHistory="true"` in `AndroidManifest` caused all the trouble for me.

Comment: android:noHistory="true" in AndroidManifest helped thanxx a lot @MarcoW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope following Code will help you.

```
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[]
    { "publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access" };

mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID); 
mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS,new LoginDialogListener());


private final class LoginDialogListener implements
            com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener
    {

        /**
         * Called when the dialog has completed successfully
         */
        public void onComplete(Bundle values)
        {
            // Process onComplete
            Log.d("FB Sample App", "LoginDialogListener.onComplete()");
            // Dispatch on its own thread
            mHandler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    mText.setText("Facebook login successful. Press Menu...");
                }
            });
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error)
        {
            // Process error
            Log.d("FB Sample App", "LoginDialogListener.onFacebookError()");
        }

        public void onError(DialogError error)
        {
            // Process error message
            Log.d("FB Sample App", "LoginDialogListener.onError()");
        }

        public void onCancel()
        {
            // Process cancel message
            Log.d("FB Sample App", "LoginDialogListener.onCancel()");
        }
    }
```

Comment: how come the onActivityResult isn't called ? they say on the API that it's very important to call authorizeCallback on this method , but it's not even called , no matter what happens.